# How to best work with bulk data json render in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a create method that redirects to host_calendar_path. But what could be the best way so that I could render json response with rv_date instead of single rv_date.

```
  def create
    start_date = Date.parse(rv_date_params[:start_date])
    end_date = Date.parse(rv_date_params[:end_date])

    (start_date..end_date).each do |day|
      rv_date = RvDate.where(rv_id: rv_date_params[:rv_id], start_date: day)
      if rv_date.present?
        rv_date.update_all(price: rv_date_params[:price], status: rv_date_params[:status])
      else
        rv_date = RvDate.create(rv_id: rv_date_params[:rv_id], start_date: day, end_date: day, price: rv_date_params[:price], status: rv_date_params[:status])
      end
    end
    redirect_to host_calendar_path(rv_id: rv_date_params[:rv_id])

  end
```

Is storing those to array and sending rv_date as array a good solution?
Eg:

```
 def create
    start_date = Date.parse(rv_date_params[:start_date])
    end_date = Date.parse(rv_date_params[:end_date])
    rv_dates = []

    (start_date..end_date).each do |day|
      @rv_date = RvDate.where(rv_id: rv_date_params[:rv_id], start_date: day)
      if @rv_date.present?
        @rv_date.update_all(price: rv_date_params[:price], status: rv_date_params[:status])
      else
        @rv_date = RvDate.create(rv_id: rv_date_params[:rv_id], start_date: day, end_date: day, price: rv_date_params[:price], status: rv_date_params[:status])
      end
      rv_dates << @rv_date
    end
    # redirect_to host_calendar_path(rv_id: rv_date_params[:rv_id])
    render json: rv_dates: rv_dates

end
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work, yes. Ideally, you would create a new record, called EventSeries or something, and have all the logic to create the event instances inside EventSeries.

You would end up with something like

```
post "/event_series.json", params: {start_date: some_date, end_date: some_date}
```

Then, a event_series_controller where:

```
def create
  @event_series = EventSeries.new(event_series_params)
  if @event_series.save
     render json: @event_series
  end
end
```

And then, inside EventSeries class:

```
has_many :events

before_create :prepare_events

def prepare_events
  (start_date..end_date).each do |day|
    ... code to manage events creation ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. This turned out to be helpful.